# Kotlin REPL: captured member values initialization is forbidden due to possible reassignment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In the Kotlin REPL, I tried to print an immutable value like this:

```
val a:Int
a = 5
print("Value of a is: ${a}")
```

When I execute above code in Android Studio(3.2) with Kotlin(1.2.71) it's thrown an error:

> error: captured member values initialization is forbidden due to possible reassignment
>
> a = 5
>
> ^

But when I run same part of code at [play.kotlinlang.org](https://pl.kotl.in/BycT3vVjX) then it executed successfully and print the output.

```html
<iframe src="https://pl.kotl.in/SJC7APVo7"></iframe>
```

If I do same thing with mutable valiable in Kotlin REPL then it's works fine:

```
var a:Int
a = 5
print("Value of a is: ${a}")
```

> Output - Value of a is: 5

[image]

So why I am getting above error in Kotlin REPL and also only for immutable variable?

Answer (score 1):

Property of immutable variable is that it can only be assigned once. In your case, compiler does not like the possibility of immutable variables being assigned more than once.

So, this should definitely work:

```
val a:Int = 5
print("Value of a is: ${a}")
```

As to why it is behaving differently in 2 places, it depends on the code around it. If a compiler has an easy way to make sure that value can be assigned only once, then it will allow it.

For eg:

```
val a: Int
if(*condition*) {
  a = 5
}
else {
  a = 6
}
```

will be allowed, although "a" is assigned 2 times.